# Cómo abrir una instancia de una Console App desde una WPF App o Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo esta solución de la imagen formada por dos proyectos, uno de consola y el otro de WPF. He ligado las dependencias del proyecto de WPF al de consola, de modo que puedo instanciar la clase TerminalApp desde el proyecto WPF al darle, por ejemplo, un click a un botón del UI. El problema es que si ejecuto el método estático Main desde el UI no me abre una consola con el resultado de haber lanzado ese método. He indagado por internet y no me lo han dejado demasiado claro. ¿Cómo puedo abrir la consola y que se muestre en ella el código evaluado en el método Main de la app de consola?

Os muestro la solución, muy básica, de hecho solo la he creado para reproducir este asunto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución 1**

Vas a propiedades del proyecto WPF y lo configuras como "Aplicación de consola"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera siempre se abre una consola al iniciar el proyecto e incluso desde el proyecto WPF puedes hacer `Console.Write` y se verá el resultado.

Por contra, es que la consola está siempre visible y no solo cuando presionas el botón

**Solución 2**

Usar `Process` con lo cual no necesitas agregar el proyecto `TerminalAPP` como referencia. No obstante, seguir agregándolo te facilitará encontrar la ubicación del .exe, ya que se agregará en la misma carpeta que el WPF

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "TerminalApp.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "argumento1 argumento2";
process.Start();
```

Comment: Gracias Yussef, era justo lo que quería.